# How to enable Format Picture Tools in Word while recording macro?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, format, text-editing

It's often desirable to fix some images while working in Word.
Yet when you try to record macro, some functions are NOT available, for example, Format Picture Tools. Similar question was asked about Word 2007, but it seems still not answered as of Word 2013, for example.

How to unlock (turn on, access) those formatting functions for macros?